# Como puedo actualizar PHP

Tags: php, mysql, composer, apache2

Buen dia en mi trabajo tenemos un pequeño servidor en el que subimos todos los proyectos de la empresa el anterior programador usaba apache2.4 y ahi mismo php pero el 5.6

Y todo bien no habia tenido ningun problema con mis proyectos hasta ahora que realice un proyecto que se encarga de importar un archivo de excel a mysql para registrar unos datos entonces al ejecutarlo en el servidor me dice lo siguiente

Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 5.6.9. in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ScanningHour\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 25

Entonces quiero saber si hay alguna manera de actualizar la version de php sin afectar a los demas proyectos

De antemano gracias

Comment: Hola actualizar el PHP afectara a todos tus proyectos

Comment: @CriticalGhost entonces de plano tendria que buscar otra opcion de realizar el proyecto verdad

Comment: si no puedes actualizar el php por los proyectos, tendras que buscar algun metodo para hacer lo que buscas en tu version de php, si no lo encontras tendras que actualizar el php

Comment: Buenas mi recomendación si no puedes actualizar PHP, seria que o uses una MV, muy costoso pero muy moldeable, o que uses un conteiner de docker

Comment: @CriticalGhost no pues entonces si voy a tener que ocupar actualizar por que nadamas no encuentro manera de hacer lo que ya tengo pero sin el composer

Comment: @DavidGonzalo disculpa un poco mi ignarancia pero como seria usar el conteiner de docker la verdad no estoy familiarizado con eso

Comment: @AlbertoCruz es bastante fácil de usar, pero difícil de explicar en un comentario, mi recomendación es que mires algún video tutorial en Youtube, o mires la documentación de Docker

Comment: @DavidGonzalo Enterado muchas gracias revisare lo que encuentre  y vere si me funciona

Comment: Lo ideal sería actualizar PHP para tener un versión más reciente, sin embargo afectara a la mayoría sino es que a todos tus proyectos y te haría trabajar mas. La otra opción es buscar una versión de la biblioteca que sea compatible con tu versión actual de PHP. También se puede levantar otro servidor web con otro puerto y la versión necesaria de PHP.

Comment: Hace falta información  `pequeño servidor`  no dice nada.    Necesitamos saber  `Sistema operativo`  si es Windows  utilizaras  `XAMP` . `MAMP`  u otro

Comment: @WilfredoAleman Que tal tienes razon es un pequeño servidor local el cual trabaja con windows 10 y apache 2.4 el cual contiene PHP 5.6 y hasta el momento no habia tenido problema para implementar mis proyectos hasta ahora que empece a utilizar PHPSPREADSHEET el cual tengo que descargar mediante compose y compose pide minimo PHP 7 entonces al ejecutar mi proyecto me arroja la alerta de la version de php "Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 5.6.9." ya actualice al PHP8 pero fallaron algunos proyectos